# How do I apply session stickiness with nginx-ingress on just one backend service?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I've got an Ingress object with multiple backends, like this:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    fabric8.io/generated-by: exposecontroller
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 500m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: '172800'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: '172800'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my-app.<tld>
      secretName: tls-my-app
  rules:
    - host: my-app.<tld>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /_ui/
            backend:
              serviceName: ui
              servicePort: 443
          - backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 443
```

I only need session stickiness on my `api` service. But the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie` annotation applies to all backend services. Does someone know how I can accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations are [applied to every `path`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#building-the-nginx-model) (location) defined on your `Ingress` object. If you need different annotations for each path, you could create one different `Ingress` for each `path`:

> - Annotations are applied to all the paths in the Ingress.
> - Multiple Ingresses can define different annotations. These definitions are not shared between Ingresses.
> - If multiple Ingresses define different paths for the same host, the    ingress controller will merge the definitions.

Nginx Ingress Controller will watch and collect those `Ingress` rules, applying them accordingly.

For example:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: my-app-ui
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    fabric8.io/generated-by: exposecontroller
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    # No session affinity here
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 500m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: '172800'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: '172800'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my-app.<tld>
      secretName: tls-my-app
  rules:
    - host: my-app.<tld>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /_ui/
            backend:
              serviceName: ui
              servicePort: 443
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: my-app-api
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    fabric8.io/generated-by: exposecontroller
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie  # <-- Session affiniy is here
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 500m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: '172800'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: '172800'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my-app.<tld>
      secretName: tls-my-app
  rules:
    - host: my-app.<tld>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /_api/
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 443
---
```

*Note: The API `extensions/v1beta1` was [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/) on Kubernetes 1.16. Consider migrating to `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`.*

Comment: Thank you. Looks like that should help. Does having 2 Ingresses with the same hostname have any adverse impact though?

Comment: No problem at all. As per [Building the NGINX model](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#building-the-nginx-model): _If multiple Ingresses define different paths for the same host, the ingress controller will merge the definitions._

Comment: thanks again. that worked beautifully well. this is sort of a follow up question. Do you know how I can expose the 2 services using https://github.com/jenkins-x/exposecontroller ? I was setting the `fabric8.io/ingress.name: my-app` for both services so that one ingress was created. But I'm finding it hard figuring out how to expose the services on 2 ingresses which share the same host

Comment: I don't have experience with Jenkins/Fabric8, sorry. I suggest you create another question addressing that and include a link to this one to help provide context. Maybe someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up creating an issue/feature request; https://github.com/jenkins-x/exposecontroller/issues/195. From what I could tell from looking at the code base, it didn't seem possible at the moment.